# Finding max and min integers from user input using for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, max, min

The following code intends to ask the user to specify the number of integers they would like to input and then find and display the maximum and minimum values between them. However, it's not compiling, and it might be because of the way I initialized the minInt and maxInt variables, but I'm unsure. Please help! Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
        int inNum, inInt, minInt, maxInt, i;

        minInt = INT_MAX;
        maxInt = INT_MIN;
        cout << "How many numbers would you like to enter?" << endl;
        cin >> inNum;
        cout << "Please enter " << inNum << " integers." << endl;
        for(i = 0 ; i < inNum; i++)
        {
                cin >> inInt >> endl;
                if(inInt > maxInt)
                {
                        maxInt = inInt;
                }
                if(inInt < minInt)
                {
                        minInt = inInt;
                }
        }
        cout << "min: " << minInt << endl;
        cout << "max: " << maxInt << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message (and which line is it)?

Comment: `cin >> inInt >> endl;` `endl` tells the output stream to print a newline and flush the stream to the underlying medium. It shouldn't be in an input statement.

Comment: You also need to `#include <climits>`.

Comment: Also, the C++ way of using C's `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` is, respectively, `numeric_limits<int>::max()` and `numeric_limits<int>::min()`, found in `<limits>`.

Comment: Here are the error messages pasted below:                            minmax.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
minmax.cpp:7:11: error: ‘INT_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
  minInt = INT_MAX;
           ^
minmax.cpp:8:11: error: ‘INT_MIN’ was not declared in this scope
  maxInt = INT_MIN;
           ^
minmax.cpp:14:16: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_istream<char>::__istream_type {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’)
   cin >> inInt >> endl;

Comment: But it looks like they've been covered by the replies given. I'll retest the code and update you all in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found 2 errors:

1. `<climits>` is not included, where `INT_MAX`and `INT_MIN` is defined
2. And `cin` does not support `endl`

So the code should be somenthing like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int inNum, inInt, minInt, maxInt, i;

    minInt = INT_MAX;
    maxInt = INT_MIN;
    cout << "How many numbers would you like to enter?" << endl;
    cin >> inNum;
    cout << "Please enter " << inNum << " integers." << endl;
    for(i = 0 ; i < inNum; i++)
    {
            //Error 3: cin >> inInt >> endl; cin does not support endl
            cin >> inInt;
            if(inInt > maxInt)
            {
                    maxInt = inInt;
            }
            if(inInt < minInt)
            {
                    minInt = inInt;
            }
    }
    cout << "min: " << minInt << endl;
    cout << "max: " << maxInt << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, when I rewrote the code according to your suggestions, it compiles, but it isn't working properly. For example, if I were to specify that I wanted to input two integers, and then input 1 and 2, my max would be 2 but the min would be 0.

Comment: I think It has to be the `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` values, let me edit my answer

Comment: Ah I see the reasoning now. If both were defined as 0, if my input were all positive integers above zero, then the min would have always been 0. Anyways, thanks for the help, Alejandro!!

Comment: `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are defined in [`<climits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) and should not be self defined like you have done.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your problem:

```
cin >> inInt >> endl;
```

You don't need to have `endl` here.

```
cin >> inInt;
```